# Integrating facebook in ios 5 gives error

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am creating an app that do login using facebook.I am using facebook SDK 3.1 but it shows me error , i have added facebook.framwork and resourcefole to my project but still it shows error.

Here is the error report.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_open_v2", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      ___36-[FBCacheIndex initWithCacheFolder:]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_close", referenced from:
      ___23-[FBCacheIndex dealloc]_block_invoke_0 in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_finalize", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_errmsg", referenced from:
      _releaseStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_bind_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_bind_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_step", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _removeEntryFromDatabaseForKey:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _dropTrimmingTable] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      ...
  "_sqlite3_prepare_v2", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_reset", referenced from:
      _initializeStatement in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_text", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
  "_sqlite3_column_int", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _readEntryFromDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _fetchCurrentDiskUsage] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _trimDatabase] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get endefined symbols error due to sqlite3.

In other linker flags in Build Settings of XCode project make sure you set the flag 
-lsqlite3.0.Make sure you set it beside adding frameworks Accounts,AdSupport,Social.